# linear regression with gradient descendet , residual sum of squares overflow

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

Hi I was trying to learn about regression algorithms and with that I tried implemented a linear regression with gradient descent and use the residual sum of squares to determine convergence.
I notice that at some point in the iterations the evaluation of the residual sum of squares, I think it makes sense but I don't know how to solve this problem. I am doing something wrong?

```
import math
import numpy as num

def get_regression_predictions(input_feature, intercept, slope):
   predicted_output = [intercept + xi*slope for xi in input_feature]
   return(predicted_output)

def get_residual_sum_of_squares(input_feature, output, intercept,slope):
   return num.sum( [(output.iloc[i] - (intercept + slope*input_feature.iloc[i]))**2 for i in range(0,len(output))] )

def train(input_feature,output,intercept,slope):
#the start value of intercept and slope are 0
    last = 0
    now = math.sqrt(get_residual_sum_of_squares(input_feature,output,intercept,slope))

    while abs(last - now) >= 0.01:
        last = now
        predictions = get_regression_predictions(input_feature,intercept,slope)
        errors = [output.iloc[i] - predictions[i] for i in range(0,len(predictions))]


        adjustements = (sum(errors)*0.05,sum([errors[i]*output.iloc[i] for i in range(0,len(errors))] ) *0.05)

        intercept ,slope = (intercept - adjustements[0],slope - adjustements[1] )
        now = math.sqrt(get_residual_sum_of_squares(input_feature,output,intercept,slope))

 return intercept,slope
```

Comment: I could not get the posted code to run "as is", and it seems not to have any data to be fitted.

Answer (score 0):

Try stochastic gradient descent. You are probably summing up lots of instance errors leading to the overflow.